# AWS: Order of importance for EC2 containers running on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a requirement to run 5-6 services on an ECS EC2 cluster. Each of these services autoscale based on the below settings. I am using EC2 instance type t2.large which has [max number of ENI's set to 3.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html)

As the ENI's are set by AWS, I experience RESOURCE: ENI error when the number of services autoscale. Currently, I am remediating this issue by autoscaling the ec2 instances.

It looks like AWS assigns 1 private IP per container and the max eni's on an instance determine the number of containers that can be run on EC2.

- service1 (min: 1, max: 2)
- service2 (min: 1, max: 2)
- service3 (min: 1, max: 10)
- service4 (min: 1, max: 1)
- service5 (min: 1, max: 1)
- service6 (min: 1, max: 1)

Question:

1. Is there a way to let ECS know that in the case all services are maxed out and there are no ENI's left, at a minimum, we will need one instance of service1, service2 running in the cluster. ECS takes the decision of autoscaling but I want to specify an order of priority.
2. Maxing out ENI's on an instance looks like a common problem. Is there a recommended way of autoscaling the eni's on an instance instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: If you switch from `awsvpc` networking to `bridge`, it will no longer allocate an ENI per container.

Comment: may I know what is the downsides of using bridge mode for networking? I might need SG per container.

Comment: I didn't see anything clear in the docs. Last time I used ECS (about 3-4 years ago), `bridge` was the default mode and `awsvpc` mode was not available yet.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-microservices-deploy-options/issues/137#issuecomment-379869961

This doc provides differences between the two. I will try with bridge mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question after some research on this topic:

1. Is there a way to autoscale based on available ENI's or provide a priority for services?

Currently, there is no clear path to autoscale services on EC2 machine based on the number of free ENI's on the instance nor provide a priority.

Few considerations:

a. Fargate could be an option if it fits your use case as there is no documented limit on the number of ENI's on fargate. In either case, make sure that the VPC has enough available IP addresses as it eventually boils down to a number of IP addresses being allocated.

b. Determine if awsvpc is required for your service or can bridge mode serve the purpose.

---

2. Maxing out ENI's on an instance looks like a common problem. Is there a recommended way of autoscaling the eni's on an instance instead of creating a new instance?

No. AWS provides
[trunking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html) option.